# Почему возникает эта ошибка и как ее решить?

Tags: java, android

Why this error occur and how to solve this ?
The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "meta-data" is not bound.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.bottomnavigation">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <meta-data
                    tools:replace="android:value"
                    android:name="android.support.VERSION"
                    android:value="26.0.0" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В манифесте добавьте такую строку:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Например так должно быть:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.winanainc"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

и дальше добавьте тег в само тело application:

```
<application>
   ...
   ..
    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" />
</application>
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140059/add-toolsreplace-androidvalue-to-meta-data-element-at-androidmanifest) есть подобный вопрос.

P.S. Переведите ваш вопрос на русский пожалуйста, и добавьте немного конкретики :)